# Size of png-files for ImageButtons in android activity

Tags: android, android-resources, android-imagebutton

I am working on an app that uses **ImageButtons** instead of normal Buttons. Each ImageButton has a **.png-file** as backgroundsource. I made the files with the Android Asset Studio and so have each file in different sizes:

- xxxhdpi
- xxhdpi
- xhdpi
- hdpi
- mdpi
- web, hi-res

At the moment I always take the png-file with the highest quality, in this case web hi-res, and set it to the ImageView with scaleType **"centerCrop"**. So what I do is taking a very big picture and put it in a small imagebutton (about **50x50dp**). This of course gives me no pixels on the border, which is nice and I need.

But does this cost lots of **resources**? 
Should I take one of the smaller pngs? 
Which one is the right for a size like 50x50dp?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: Am I reading that right: Until a width of 160dp a mdpi is enough!?

Comment: At mdpi (160 dpi), 1dp = 1px. At hdpi (240 dpi), 1dp = 1.5px. And so on.